Scheduled Tasks or Cronjobs with App Platform Worker
I'm looking to use App Platform for hosting some custom code. This is meant to be a scheduled type of task, so from what I understand, I'd want to set up a Worker component to run in the background. I have seen the docs and repo about the cron using Docker, over in the DigitalOcean-AppPlatform-Cron repo.
But I couldn't find clarification on details regarding this Worker component. Is it a long running resource? I seem to be getting mixed answers as I search the internet, so I just wanted to be sure. I was thinking that if it was, then I could use something like node-cron within a script, and then have the Worker instance execute this script so that I can run some cron jobs. But I'd love to hear if this wouldn't work.
Thanks in advance.

I actually just finished up doing this on app platform and laravel. The problem we had was AppPlatform doesn't support cron, and we are using buildpacks. Our workaround was creating a new component on AppPlatform, choosing the same repo (which is where our tasks were), picking the smallest resource size.
Once that was deployed, we edited the run parameters to the following:
while true; do
    echo "=> Running scheduler"
    php artisan schedule:run || true;
    echo "=> Sleeping for 60 seconds"
    sleep 60;
done

If you're not using Laravel, replace php artisan schedule:run || true; with whatever command you need.
Hope this helps!
